# Triggered Send from POS push tracking into CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, marketing-cloud-connect

We have a Triggered Send through the API configured from a POS. We would like to send this tracking back into the CRM through the Connector integration.

1. The original Trigger was set-up prior to the implementation of the Connector.
2. The Connector is configured and sending tracking back from Saleforce Sends and Journeys.
3. The API Triggers are not sending tracking back.

The original Triggers were set-up to have the TSD Data Extensions in the Data Extensions folder. I have tried moving them to Salesforce Data Extensions and tracking is still not getting pushed into Salesforce.

My understanding was if a Sending DE is in Salesforce Data Extensions and it has the Subscriber Key as the Contact ID then tracking should be sent back to CRM.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to push tracking to the Core Clouds I would assume that the addressed contacts exist in there at the time of send. Are there reasons that would hinder you from pushing the POS data to the CRM? Once in there it would be easier to trigger a send (e.g. via Journey Builder) that pushes tracking data back.

Comment: TSDs are legacy and existed before we set-up the Connector. Scope of work does not include redesign of TSDs.

Comment: Have you tested if a guided send to those data extensions in the SF DE folder pushes tracking data back to Salesforce? This might help narrowing down the issue to either the data source or the triggered send setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work with Triggered Send emails.

The only solution that I can think of is to create a journey (with a single Send Email Activity) and use the REST API [events method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm) to serialize the Contact data into the entry source DE and inject them into a Journey. You can then configure the Send Email Activity to send the tracking results to Sales Cloud, as per the screenshot below.

[image: Send Tracking Results to Sales Cloud]

To confirm, you can only get tracking information in Sales Cloud for:

1. Salesforce Email Sends sent from [Sales Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_send_single_email.htm&type=5) or Marketing Cloud (Interactions menu > Salesforce Send Emails)
2. Email sends that are sent to a Salesforce Campaign or Report in Email Studio (which actually creates a Salesforce Email Send behind the scenes)
3. [Salesforce Triggered Sends](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_create_a_triggered_send.htm&type=5)
4. Send Email Activities in Journey Builder.

Comment: Thanks Eliot, So is it fair to say that Triggered Sends cannot be used to synchronize tracking data back to Salesforce CRM even when the Connector is installed?

Comment: That's right (with the exception of Salesforce Triggered Sends which update the Lead or Contact Record with tracking information). I've updated my answer to clarify this.

Comment: @Eliot - i believe Content Builder Sends to a Data Extension located in the Salesforce Data Extension folder also synchronizes tracking. This was the case a while back. You can also get tracking flowing via Automated Studio Salesforce Sends.

Comment: Victorcorey - please select Eliot's as "Best Answer" if it's solved your question to mark the question as resolved :)